# UIButton not going changing text color when there is long-press gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, long-press, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have the following code:

```
deleteAllButton.setTitle("Delete", forState: .Normal)
        deleteAllButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        deleteAllButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        deleteAllButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(keyboardFontSize)
    //  deleteAllButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deletekeyPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        let deleteLPGR = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(deleteButtonLongPress))
        deleteLPGR.minimumPressDuration = 0
        deleteLPGR.delaysTouchesBegan = true

        deleteAllButton.addGestureRecognizer(deleteLPGR)
```

Normally when a UIButton is pressed the text automatically changes color to indicate it is in a "pressed" state. However, since I have added the long press gesture recognizer the button does not indicate that it is in a "pressed" state.

How can I still allow a touch event to go through to the button so the user feels like the button is infact "pressed"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to add gesture recognizer.

just try to set titlecolor for state highlited and it should work

```
deleteAllButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
```

hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `deleteLPGR.minimumPressDuration = 0` to `deleteLPGR.minimumPressDuration = 1` then you can notice the color change when you press